# Redirect user to specific link after login

Tags: redirect, login, user-access, username

I am new to wordpress so I will surely need more help than others to understand your answers. So, the question is:
I have this website with a login page on home. Let's supose you are a member. If you want to log in, you should put your username and password, right? 
Let's suppose your username is **Malcovich**. After you put your username and password, you click on "enter the website" button, and immediatly you will be redirected to www.mywebsite/**MALCOVICH**

How can I do that? How can I redirect people after log in to a specific page that is named as the username they use to access the website?

And also I want to put a voice "PROFILE" in the menu that does the same thing, redirects people to a page named as their username. And I want this button in menu to be seen only by loged in people.

Thank you very much for being my saviors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login_redirect filter should works (add this code into your theme functions.php):

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    $redirect_to =  home_url($user->user_nicename);
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

For "PROFILE" in the menu (add this code into your template file where you want to display it):

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( $current_user->user_nicename ) ) . '">PROFILE</a>';
}
```

UPDATE: If you manage menu from backend, I don't know if any better solution, but this will works:

Add a custom menu item with name "PROFILE", and add this code in your theme functions.php:

```
function filter_nav_menu_items( $menu ) {
  if ( $menu->title == 'PROFILE' ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $menu->url = home_url( $current_user->user_nicename );
    }
    else {
      $menu->_invalid = true;
    }
  }

  return $menu;
}
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'filter_nav_menu_items', 999 );
```

Comment: Hi, I'm really happy your advice worked perfectly. Now users are redirected to their own page after login. I have another question. Where should I put the code for the profile button in menu?

Comment: I updated my answer. It should works for you.